# How to copy an object from one blend file to another via python?

Tags: python

I want to copy an object via python from one scene to another.

Scene with the object:
[image: A keyframed Cube]

Scene where i want to copy it to:
[image: A more complex scene were the keyframed Cube got copied into]

Comment: @poor almost but i dont want to append groups, just a single object.

Comment: The Python code is pretty much the same as for groups. Just point it to the object instead.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. As you may already noticed, it's basically the same for an object: https://gist.github.com/p2or/2d629206158e5c4162a1491bcc6e0e5c Further info [here](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.BlendDataLibraries.html). Let me know if there is something you do not understand @froggyman